# Android ActionView With Title Showing

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionview

So I achieved setting a custom ActionView for a MenuItem inside my ActionBar,  great!
Now,  how do I keep the menuItem showing it's title (set in xml)?

This is important as I want users to read what that button is doing.
The customView serves as a regular menuItem and is always expanded.

I tried setting ContentDescription to the custom layout containing the same title,  but no luck so far.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the content description, but in the constructor of your custom layout, setup [Roman Nurik's CheatSheet](https://gist.github.com/romannurik/3982005). When you're using a custom `MenuItem`, it's up to you to make it accessible.

```
public ActionViewExample(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // Ensure the MenuItem is accessible
    CheatSheet.setup(this);
}
```

Comment: And....That works perfectly!:)  
Thank you so much! Can't believe there isn't a 'built in' option..